# Entity attribute not passed to sql statement with hibernateTemplate

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am learning spring data access and I've tried to insert data through hibernateTempate. Here is my code:

**UPDATED**

applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.eric.mvnlab"/>

    <context:property-placeholder properties-ref="properties"/>

    <bean id="properties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:application.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages"/>
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="${source.encoding}"/>
    </bean>


    <!-- DAO layer -->
    <tx:annotation-driven/>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        ...
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate session factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <!--<property name="packagesToScan" value="com.eric.mvnlab.model.*" />-->
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.eric.mvnlab.model.Machine</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

MachineDAO.java

```
package com.eric.mvnlab.server.dao.impl;

import com.eric.mvnlab.model.Machine;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository("machineDao")
public class MachineDAO extends GenericHibernateDAOImpl<Machine, Integer> {
    public void addMachine(Machine machine) {
        getHibernateTemplate().save(machine);
    }

    public Machine findById(int id) {
        return (Machine) getHibernateTemplate().get(Machine.class, id);
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
package com.eric.mvnlab;

import com.eric.mvnlab.model.Machine;
import com.eric.mvnlab.server.dao.impl.MachineDAO;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

/**
 * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: eric
 * Date: 9/25/12
 * Time: 3:15 PM
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        MachineDAO machineDAO = (MachineDAO)context.getBean("machineDao");
        machine.setHostname("MyLaptop");
        machine.setIpaddress("127.0.0.1");
        machineDAO.addMachine(machine);
    }
}
```

Machine.java

```
package com.eric.mvnlab.model;

import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;

@Entity
@Table(name="MACHINE")
public class Machine {
    @Column(name="MID")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)

    private int mid;

    @Column(name="HOSTNAME")
    private String hostname;

    @Column(name="IPADDRESS")
    private String ipaddress;

    public String getIpaddress() {
        return ipaddress;
    }

    public void setIpaddress(String ipaddress) {
        this.ipaddress = ipaddress;
    }

    public String getHostname() {
        return hostname;
    }

    public void setHostname(String hostname) {
        this.hostname = hostname;
    }

    public int getMid() {
        return mid;
    }

    public void setMid(int machineId) {
        this.mid = machineId;
    }
}
```

Table Machine has three columns: mid, hostname and ipaddress. mid is the primary key and is auto increment.

When I run Main, I got below output:

```
Hibernate: insert into MACHINE (MID, HOSTNAME, IPADDRESS) values (null, ?, ?)
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not insert: [com.eric.mvnlab.model.Machine]; SQL [insert into MACHINE (MID, HOSTNAME, IPADDRESS) values (null, ?, ?)]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert: [com.eric.mvnlab.model.Machine]
WARN  - JDBCExceptionReporter      - SQL Error: -798, SQLState: 428C9
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:629)
ERROR - JDBCExceptionReporter      - DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-798, SQLSTATE=428C9, SQLERRMC=MID, DRIVER=4.7.85
```

Could anyone tell me why the entity attribute data is not passed to sql statement?

**NOTE:**
If you are using DB2 9.7, and you are likely to met this error:

*org.hibernate.HibernateException: The database returned no natively generated identity value*

It's a DB2 jdbc driver bug, and the solution is to use a later version driver, such as 10.1

Comment: Everything looks correct so far. Can you show your `Machine` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you configured Hibernate to use HSQLDB dialect, whereas your error message comes from DB2. You need to configre a dialect that matches your DBMS, see [3.4.1. SQL Dialects](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional-dialects).

Comment: Thanks for your correction, I've changed it to org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect, the output is now: Hibernate: insert into MACHINE (MID, HOSTNAME, IPADDRESS) values (default, ?, ?), why the hostname and ipaddress still not set in SQL code?

Comment: They are set. Hibernate uses JDBC prepared statements. The question marks are parameters of the prepared statement. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html. If you want to log the value of the parameters, you need to set the logging level of `org.hibernate.type` to DEBUG. See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#configuration-logging